# Unable to load the image

Tags: apex, visualforce, amazon, aws

I'm getting a GET error and the image doesn't show up . It is unable to load the image . Banging my head on this . Please help. The error is below,

> 403 (Forbidden)
>          GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file_name?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGN4J4RSRNW26IEA&Expires=1415795641&Signature=Wdp6XU%2FF9E2lQ6fpzKbR0eF5OlM%3D

| EDIT|  Code as below

```
public pageReference redirectToS3Key() {


        //get the filename in urlencoded format
        String filename = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('filename'), 'UTF-8');
        //String bucket = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bucket'), 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('redirectToS3Key filename: ' + filename);
        Datetime now = DateTime.now();
        Datetime expireson = now.AddSeconds(20000); // timeout issue from here.
        Long Lexpires = expireson.getTime()/1000;

        System.debug('key: ' + as3.key);
        System.debug('secret: ' + as3.secret);
        //String codedFilename=  EncodingUtil.urlEncode(filename,'UTF-8');
       // System.debug('codedFilename: '+codedFilename); 
        String stringtosign = 'GET\n\n\n'+Lexpires+'\n/'+bucketToList+'/'+filename;
        System.debug('redirectToS3Key stringstosign: ' + stringtosign);
        String signed = make_sig(stringtosign);
        System.debug('signed: ' + signed);
        String codedsigned = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signed,'UTF-8');
        System.debug('codedsigned: ' + codedsigned);
       // String url = 'http://'+bucketToList+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+filename+'?AWSAccessKeyId='+as3.key+'&Expires='+Lexpires+'&Signature='+signed;

        String url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/'+ bucketToList + '/' +filename+'?AWSAccessKeyId='+as3.key+'&Expires='+Lexpires+'&Signature='+signed;

        System.debug('url: ' + url);
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference(url);
        System.debug('newPage url: ' + newPage.getUrl());
        System.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%'+newPage);
        return newPage;

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: How did you generate the link? Note, that for now the link returns `Request has expired` message instead of `403`. Please provide more details about your trouble

Comment: @Panvel , i've  referred my code. Request expired error comes when there is a timeout issue . So sometimes image shows up and sometime it doesnt . What basically i need is display the image on clicking particular bucket name .

Comment: @JJoseph 1) Did you white list the hostnames /IP in both the environments? 2) Are you sure the the Access Key your're supplying in the URL is valid? I think it is an authentication issue!

Comment: I did checked IP as well as Access key and i do not see any problem . I'm really stucked to get this image .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I increased the time substantially. May be that might help in your case too.Try and let us know if that helps or there might be another problem.

**Datetime expireson = now.AddSeconds(800010);**